# How to Interaction google map api with application browser

Tags: api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

It’s a general process  when User want to  access google map api then application has to communicate with google for information.

Want to know how browser established communication with google  and what steps are involved in?

**Note:** failed to find information from https://developers.google.com/maps how to communicate google with browser and what steps are involved. It’s show me information how to use api and how to configure it,if i am not wrong.

Comment: If you are talking about JavaScript API, you can view [the sample demos](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple). First you need to provide an API key, then you can call the API methods or Web Services, it will do some HTTP requests, then in the call back listener(or JSON/XML response in Web Services), Google Maps APIs will return you corresponding results.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially `"google maps"` is a collection of services, you set the services you need in the link to google maps where also indicate your API key.

The google maps services are in javascript the executed in the browser and this command send several requesto toi google for the various need, eg: satellite maps tile, geocoding, streetView image, lat lng positioning and so on...

This tipically require an internet connection and the goggle services can't used without connection

The argoument is very broad, this are only a few tips..

Comment: scaisEdge thanks for your reply, you said browser send request to google for various need,what's it want to know main steps that are involved on exchanging request.After load a simple map you may see chrome developer tools AUDIT and Network tab .

Comment: The steps are different by request. In some case( simple maps) you call a function with parameters and google send you an answer containing the code for retrive the maps and/or the maps  tile. You can see this in firebug. For geocodeding you call the function and the response are an object (JSON) cointaing the result.

Comment: You can  try with a simple map and explore with inspector like chrome dev tools, firefox developer or firebug.

Comment: All  result contain javscript object and you cant interct with this. And you can also add  event listener on the various object for automation and reaction